# How to get froala's parent div's data-id attribute?

Tags: jquery, froala

So I have the editor mostly setup for inlineMode.

Here's what my implementation code currently looks like:

```
<article class="post editable" data-save-id="post-mission_statement">

$('.editable').editable({
    inlineMode: true,
    saveURL: 'http://www.unicon.church/admin/save.php',    
    saveRequestType: 'POST',
    autosave: true,
    autosaveInterval: 2500
});
$(".editable").on('editable.beforeSave', function (e, editor, data) {
    // HOW THE HECK do I figure out what the data-save-id is?!?!
    console.log(e);
    // I want to do 
    // editor.option('saveParams', { postId: $(parentDiv).data('saveId') });
    // but due to lack of examples and proper documentation, I don't even know if that is right.
});
```

How do I pass the context of the edit box (the `post-mission_statement`) to Froala and then to the AJAX request, so PHP can figure out the proper primary key to store the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).data('save-id')` is what you're looking for. `this` contains the DOM element you're adding the event on.

Comment: Much gracias, senor ;)